# How can I count register's traffic by a date column?

Tags: mysql

Given the following data:

```
| id | region | name  | date               |
|100 | 50     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 13:00:00|
|101 | 58     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 14:03:55|
|102 | 58     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 14:03:59|
|103 | 50     | MARY  | 2015-08-21 13:02:00|
|104 | 40     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 14:04:15|
|105 | 50     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 14:05:01|
|106 | 58     | MARY  | 2015-08-21 14:10:55|
|107 | 50     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 14:30:00|
|108 | 58     | JHONY | 2015-08-21 15:00:00|
```

I need to know the Mary and Jhony's traffic between two specified regions. Is it possible obtain it through SQL so that it seems like the following result?

```
JHONY, 2
MARY, 1
```

Therefore, it indicates that I have three movements from 50 to 58 in total. Jhony has moved from 50 to 58 twice (id 100/101 and id 107/108) and Mary has moved one time from 50 to 58 (id 103/106) ignoring the duplicate data and considering the date flow (and considering other possible names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, count(*) 
    from 
      (select t1.name,  t1.region f,  t2.region t 
           from t t1 
             left join 
                t t2 
             on t1.date < t2.date and t1.name=t2.name 
         where t1.name='JHONY' 
         group by t1.id) t3 
  where f=50 and t=58
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9434e1/2)

**UPDATE** due to the question update

```
select name, count(*) 
    from 
      (select t1.name, t1.region f, t2.region t 
           from t t1 
             left join 
                t t2 
             on t1.date < t2.date and t1.name=t2.name 
         group by t1.name, t1.id
      ) t3 
  where f=50 and t=58 
  group by name
```

Comment: It works fine, but in this example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f17be/2), I added the clause WHERE by date and does not work properly, why not? The query should have ignore the record #107 and results 2 counts, not 3.

Comment: I found the solution, I changed to `where t1.date like '2015-08-22%' and t2.date like '2015-08-22%'`

Comment: Sometimes I face a complicated issue like this, and I receive a very high-level answer that solves it... but unfortunately, it gain few attention and few people have similar problem, therefore gain fewer points. In other hand, there are simpler questions that gaint hundreds of points. It is not fair...

Comment: i think that 1) there is no clear criteria of question's difficulty and 2) good answers gather points long time (i hope) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the previous region in various ways.  Here is one:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.region
        from table t2
        where t2.name = t.name and t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_region
from table t;
```

You can then add your conditions to this:

```
select name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.region
              from table t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_region
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_region = 50 and region = 58
group by name;
```

Comment: Your query worked fine when I want to see the flow between 50 and 58, but not vice-versa, from 58 to 50, what would get result 'JHONY 1' (id 102 and 104). Is it possible?

Comment: At really, I would want to list all names traveling between 50 and 58, not only JHONY... and it would not be necessary list the name, only the occurrence traffic. In this case, the number 2 would suffice. If I had other 'name' travelling between 50 and 58 (MARY, for example), it would be 3 and so on... (sorry for bad explanation, I updated the question)

Comment: @dellasavia . . . In that case, remove the final `group by` clause and `name` from the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT region)-1 as region_changes
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-08-21 13:00:00' AND '2015-08-21 15:00:00'
GROUP BY name
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/898ff/5